# Does PHP timezone observe Daylight Saving?

Tags: php, timezone

If I set my Php timezone,should I expect Daylight Saving or not?If I don't want it to,how will I set that?

Answer (score 0):

[How can I detect day light savings automatically in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763935/how-can-i-detect-day-light-savings-automaticaly-in-php)

```
echo date('I', time());
```

> The I (capital i) is a 1/0 denoting whether or not daylight saving is
>   currently in effect.
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php
>
> hope it helps.

However if you need to know if a specific timezone WILL observe Daylight savings, someone has made a function here: [How to tell if a timezone observes daylight saving at any time of the year?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586552/how-to-tell-if-a-timezone-observes-daylight-saving-at-any-time-of-the-year)